# Google Sheets Formula to create a 1-column unique output range of all unique values in range of "jagged list"

Tags: filter, google-sheets, excel-formula, flatten

Document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N4cGw5eUq_3gCJh1w39qVatX9KV1_Hr-AqRHj_nbckA/edit?usp=sharing

---

### Data Expectation

At `Current Class!H3`, the table data is the data that is presented in the dropdown menu.

This data comes directly from `Meta!B7:B` ...

...which can come from one of the columns from `Students!$J$5:$O`. The column is determined by the value in `Current Class!B3`

```
      Current               Expected  | Example Data        Expect
   ---------------          --------  | ------------        ------
1) M1, M2, M3, M4             M1      |  1) M1, M2   --->   M1
2) M2                         M2      |                     M2
3) M3                 --->    M3      | --------------------------
4) M4                         M4      |  1) T4              M2
5) M5                         M5      |  2) M2       --->   T4
6) M4, M5, M6                 M6      |  3) TH3             TH3
```

As you might be able to determine, I have a possible list of items in a single row (This indicates that 1 student has multiple classes in one specific room - this case the `Yale` classroom).

**What I want is to separate the lists into individual items and to produce a 1-column output range of only unique values.**

*I have tried to use the `SPLIT()` function. While that breaks apart each item but I cannot find a solution to flatten the results to 1 column only.* But right now I have the following formula in `Meta!B7` ...

```
=iferror(Sort(Unique(Filter(Students!$J$5:$O, Find($B$6, Students!$J$4:$O$4) > 0 )), 1, true), "")
.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: whoops, forgot to sort it.

This seems to work:

```
=sort(unique(transpose(split(substitute(JOIN(", ",offset(Students!$I$5:$I$91,0,match($B$6,Students!$J$4:$O$4))),",","")," ",TRUE))),1,TRUE)
```

It:

- Offsets to find the right room reference,
- Joins all rows into one string with ", " separating each value,
- Removes all commas, and splits the string on spaces (" "),
- Transposes to get an array of rows, and then picks out the unique ones.

Interesting challenge!

Comment: Wow that is amazing! I didn't expect to get a result this fast. It will take some time for me to wrap my head around this. I do have to make a slight modification to sort the data based on `Classes!B5:B`.